# How to manage (add) users for ASP.NET Core 3.1 application externally

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, password-encryption, password-hash, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm sorry here will be no code provided, because I'm totally missing the idea.

Context: I develop two applications, both ASP.NET Core 3.1, lets call them A and B.

A is a website, exposed to the internet. Only users with a valid user account shall have access. There shall be no possibility to register one user within application A.

B is an internal (intranet) website. (Authentication with Active Directory.) From application B I want to be able to create users for application A.

Application A has NOTHING to do with Active Directory, I use the normal inbuild user administration of ASP.NET core.

Is it possible to enter the users to Application A from Application B by using the Entity Framework? Or is there any better approach? If it works with the Entity Framework, how will I be able to get the Salt value which is used by application A to salt the passwords?

For clarification: I have no questions about authentication or registration of users for application B, that all works.

Comment: So it looks like you want to point EF in your `Application B` onto ASP.NET Membership DB of `Application A`? You can have multiple `DbContexts` and connection strings in your project I believe.

Comment: You are right with your assumption. I mean this is already working, however I just don't know how I should salt the password of a new registered user in order for application A to be able to perform the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a hash of a password with the following method

```
public string CreateHash(TUser user, string password)
{
    var hasher = new PasswordHasher<TUser>();

    return (hasher.HashPassword(user, password));
}
```

The user object must not even be the one of which you want to change the password.

Answer (score 1):

Since in the comments you mentioned you are rather after how the salt is stored, I'll assume you've got EF pointing to `Application A` membership DB set up and focus on this hashing bit. I will assume you use [`UserManager`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs) to manage your passwords.

If you take a look into how passwords are being [stored](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2403) and [verified](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L842), you will notice both operations end up relying on [`PasswordHasher`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9a1810c1dbe432fc7bc7e8bc68fa22ab787c0452/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs) to do the job. It's being dependency injected into your UserManager by the framework and looking at the implementation:

```cs
private static byte[] HashPasswordV3(
      string password,
      RandomNumberGenerator rng,
      KeyDerivationPrf prf,
      int iterCount,
      int saltSize,
      int numBytesRequested)
    {
      byte[] numArray1 = new byte[saltSize];
      rng.GetBytes(numArray1);
      byte[] numArray2 = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(password, numArray1, prf, iterCount, numBytesRequested);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[13 + numArray1.Length + numArray2.Length];
      buffer[0] = (byte) 1;

      PasswordHasher<TUser>.WriteNetworkByteOrder(buffer, 1, (uint) prf); // hash type
      PasswordHasher<TUser>.WriteNetworkByteOrder(buffer, 5, (uint) iterCount); // number of iterations
      PasswordHasher<TUser>.WriteNetworkByteOrder(buffer, 9, (uint) saltSize); // salt size (although not configurable in this implementation)
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray1, 0, (Array) buffer, 13, numArray1.Length); // salt goes here
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray2, 0, (Array) buffer, 13 + saltSize, numArray2.Length); // password hash goes here
      return buffer; // this gets Base64-encoded upstream
    }
```

it appears that salt is just a random 16-byte array that gets stored along with the `hash`, `hashing function` and `number of iterations used`, therefore hashes created by one application should be readable by another without any extra work on your behalf as long as the [`PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9a1810c1dbe432fc7bc7e8bc68fa22ab787c0452/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L103) and [generating OS](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bcc962a182a273cdaa7de474528e97913373a212/src/DataProtection/Cryptography.KeyDerivation/src/PBKDF2/Pbkdf2Util.cs#L9) is the same.

Another thing to note here, since `PasswordHasher` is [dependency-injected](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/555b506a97a188583df2872913cc40b59e563da6/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), you actually can replace it with your own implementation if need be. Hopefully poking around [`PasswordHasher`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9a1810c1dbe432fc7bc7e8bc68fa22ab787c0452/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs) provides you with enough context.

Comment: Thank you timur. The bounty was about to timeout, so I gave it to you. However I did not yet verify your answer. Nevertheless thank you for your efforts. I will try your suggestions asap.